# InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, decision-tree, pygraphviz

I'm unable to visualize or write the Decision tree. How can I go about it?

Python version 3.5, Anaconda 3, I have even set the environment variables

```
    from sklearn import tree
    model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini') 
    model=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    model.fit(trainData,trainLabel)
    model.score(trainData,trainLabel)
    predicted= model.predict(testData)

    from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
    import pydot 
    import pydotplus
    dot_data = StringIO() 
    tree.export_graphviz(model, out_file=dot_data) 
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
    print(graph)
    graph.write_pdf("C:\\Users\\anagha\\Desktop\\SynehackData\\DATA\\DATA\\graph.pdf")
```

error :

```
InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the thread is a little old but today I got the same error when trying to visualize a Bayesian Network in a Jupyter notebook with the PyAgrum library.

I'm on Windows 10 using the Anaconda package management. In my case I needed to install the package `python-graphviz` using the following command:

`conda install python-graphviz`

After the installation, I just needed to restart the jupyter kernel and run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and tried a million things.
I saw that I should add to the environment variable, 'path' if you're in Windows.
I did this, restarted, Python, but it didn't work. 
I did it for graphviz and for pydotplus.

Then I saw someone used a slightly different path from what I had used.
something like 
Drive:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\MyVirtualEnv\Library\bin\graphviz
So I added that to the path, and restarted all things anaconda.
This was probably the 98th thing I tried. It worked!

I had been using a path like 
Drive:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\MyVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\graphviz, which didn't work, but I put in both, and a similar one for pydotplus.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't help for me.

I already had the following installed:

```
graphviz==2.50.0
pydotplus==2.0.2
pydot==1.4.1
```

But running `whereis dot` and `whereis graphviz`, it was clear that I was still missing the graphviz library on my operating system: for dot, the whereis command returned a path on my system, for graphviz, no path was printed by the whereis command.

**What helped for me (on Ubuntu) is running `sudo apt-get install graphviz`**, since the PyPi page of the python package graphviz (https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) mentions the following:

> To render the generated DOT source code, you also need to install [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) ([download page](https://www.graphviz.org/download/), [archived versions](https://www2.graphviz.org/Archive/stable/), [installation procedure for Windows](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/new-simplified-installation-procedure-on-windows/224)).

The download page linked to above mentioned that `sudo apt-get install graphviz` was the way to go on Ubuntu. **If you have another operating system, check the Download page above for a way to install graphviz on your specific OS.**

Answer (score -4):

You can take help of this code !!

```
import pydotplus
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
import collections

# Data Collection
X = [ [180, 15,0],     
      [177, 42,0],
      [136, 35,1],
      [174, 65,0],
      [141, 28,1]]

Y = ['man', 'woman', 'woman', 'man', 'woman']    

data_feature_names = [ 'height', 'hair length', 'voice pitch' ]

# Training
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X,Y)
# Visualize data
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf,
                                feature_names=data_feature_names,
                                out_file=None,
                                filled=True,
                                rounded=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)

colors = ('turquoise', 'orange')
edges = collections.defaultdict(list)

for edge in graph.get_edge_list():
    edges[edge.get_source()].append(int(edge.get_destination()))

for edge in edges:
    edges[edge].sort()    
    for i in range(2):
        dest = graph.get_node(str(edges[edge][i]))[0]
        dest.set_fillcolor(colors[i])

graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: you can refer this link and then refer above code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7PzqbKUm_4